# AppeEngine Flex- how to set version name instead of timestamp as version

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Whenever I deploy my app in Google App-engine Flexible, the version is based on the timestamp and each time new version will be created. In appEngine Standard we have:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>_your_app_id_</application>
  <version>alpha-001</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I need that my app will be deployed always with the same Version name instead of creating new version. How can i do this goal in the same way as Appengine Standard.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using maven with the new *google cloud tools* maven plugin to deploy your application:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

you can define the version into your `pom.xml` adding the following property:

```
<properties>  
    <app.deploy.version>alpha-001</app.deploy.version>
</properties>
```

If you are using directly the `gcloud` executable form command line, you can specify the version adding the argument `--version` like this:

```
gcloud app deploy --version alpha-001
```

You can remove the `<version>` entry from `appengine-web.xml`.